# Modifying an existing RegEx to accommodate also replacing <nbsp;>'s with a blank space

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I need your help,

How can the existing code below be modified such that it not only takes into account replacing all the `<br>`'s with `\n'`s but also all the `<nbsp;>`'s anywhere in a string with the space separator in javascript?

Here is the existing code that needs to be modified:

```
var txt = str.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/mg,"\n")
```

Comment: [You can't parse (X)HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1529630). And do you mean `&nbsp;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use something like this

```
var txt = str.replace(/<br ?/?>/g, '\n').replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');
```

but you can't do 2 replacements using 1 regex

Comment: It is possible to replace more than one string at a time. See my answer for one method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with one regexp, [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) accepts a function as the replacer so you *could* leverage that with a group match:

```js
var str = 'some string <br/> and&nbsp;something else';
var txt = str.replace(/(<br\s*\/?>|&nbsp;)/mg, function (match) {
  return match === '&nbsp;' ? ' ' : '\n';
});

document.write('<pre>' + txt + '</pre>');
```

If not, you can also chain together as many `replace` calls as you want:

```js
var str = 'some string <br/> and&nbsp;something else';
var txt = str.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/gm, '\n').replace(/&nbsp;/gm, ' ');
document.write('<pre>' + txt + '</pre>');
```

The main benefit of using one `replace` is that it won't need to check the entire string twice. However this does make the code a bit harder to read and possibly to maintain if you need to add/edit which entities you want to replace. So depending on the length of the string to be checked you would need to strike a balance between performance and readability/maintainability.